# Copying files from an inherited nuget

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I've developed a custom NuGet which uses DotNetProjects.DotNetSiemensPLCToolBoxLibrary. DotNet library includes external dlls that are copied into the output directory following these statements:

```
<Content Include="..\externalDlls\libnodave_jfkmod.dll">
  <Pack>true</Pack>
  <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
<Content Include="..\externalDlls\libnodave_jfkmod64.dll">
  <Pack>true</Pack>
  <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

However, when my custom Nuget is used in another project, DotNet dlls are shown on project tree but not copied into the output directory.

[nuget use example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veQhl.png)

If I set manually that these dlls will always be copied into output directory it works. It is posible to do so in the .csproj of my custom nuget?.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `.nuspec` file instead of csproj file.

```xml
<files>
    <!-- the dlls are copied from src to target-->
    <file src="lib\**" target="lib/{framework name}[{version}]" />
</files>
```

The link: [Support multiple .NET versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks)